# How to integrate Freeradius with Oracle Database XE(18c)?

Tags: oracle, freeradius, oracle18c

I have installed Freeradius and Oracle Database 18c XE. 
FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.20 -- it's working fine locally 
Oracle Database XE working fine.
But I can not integrate Freeradius with Oracle Database.
I need your help regarding this How can I integrate Freeradius with oracle database.
anyone can help?

Thanks 
Nandi

Comment: https://www.akadia.com/services/radius_server.html

Comment: the following link does not work https://www.akadia.com/services/radius_server.html